# qt + assimp ubuntu 15.10

Tags: qt, ubuntu, assimp

I have installed Qt creator in a ubuntu 15.10 machine.

I have added the assimp libraries using the following command line:

```
sudo apt-get install libassimp-dev
```

I am a novice using ubuntu and I am not sure where the assimp library installs. How to refer to it in my Qt application. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, (at least if you did the job correctly), includes are referenced automatically since it is inside your /usr/include or something like that.

However, you must reference the lib inside the ".pro" file like it :

`LIBS += -lassimp`

Comment: Thank you for sending me in the right direction. I had to include also an INCLUDEPATH and DEPENDENTPATH to make it work. A trivial task as I discovered that Qt does it for you by righ-clicking on the project name (projects tab) and selecting "Add Library...". Again, thank you for your help, Dino